# Itunes: Edit RSS Podcast URL

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I added a RSS feed to my favorite paying podcast. Recently I changed the password. Everytime I update the podcast it asks for user and pass. No mater how many times I enter it and select "Remember Password" it will keep asking.

I noticed that when I right click to "Get Info" on my Itunes podcast folder it has the URL in Where with the old password (`http://user:MyOLDPassword@www.myFavPodcast.com/members/podcast.xml`).

I really don't want to add another RSS feed with the new password. I have already done this and seems to point to the old password.

Is it possible to change this URL?

Comment: Which version of iTunes are you using?

Comment: I'm on 11.0.4.4